# How can I reference variables of generic types?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to implement a "base DAO" interface for the Room library so as to avoid boilerplate code:

**BaseEntity.kt**

```
interface BaseEntity {
    val entityName: String
}
```

**Note.kt**

```
@Entity
class Note : BaseEntity {
    override val entityName: String = "note"
    ...
}
```

**BaseDao.kt**

```
interface BaseDao<T : BaseEntity> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${T.entityName}")
    fun selectAll(): List<T>
    ...

}
```

**NoteDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface NoteDao : BaseDao<Note> {
...
}
```

However, the expression `${T.entityName}` is invalid. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible due to type erasure on the JVM. If this was a method, you could mark it as inline and mark T as reified. However, because it's a annotation, I'm not sure

Comment: Annotations require compile-time constants, this `@Query` in the `BaseDao` will unfortunately not work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you can *implement a "base DAO" interface*. The reason is that *Room creates each DAO implementation at compile time.* And hence why you get the message ***An annotation argument must be a compile time-constant***.

Room needs to know, from the annotation (for example), which table columns to map to which variables and the methods used to perform the mapping so that the underlying code can be generated.

As an example if the Entity and the Dao were :-

```
@Entity
class Note {

    @PrimaryKey
    var entityName: String = ""

}
```

and

```
@Dao
interface BaseDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Note")
    fun selectAll(): List<Note>

}
```

Then the underlying generated java would be :-

```
public final class BaseDao_Impl implements BaseDao {
  private final RoomDatabase __db;

  public BaseDao_Impl(RoomDatabase __db) {
    this.__db = __db;
  }

  @Override
  public List<Note> selectAll() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM Note";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, false, null);
    try {
      final int _cursorIndexOfEntityName = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "entityName");
      final List<Note> _result = new ArrayList<Note>(_cursor.getCount());
      while(_cursor.moveToNext()) {
        final Note _item;
        _item = new Note();
        final String _tmpEntityName;
        _tmpEntityName = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfEntityName);
        _item.setEntityName(_tmpEntityName);
        _result.add(_item);
      }
      return _result;
    } finally {
      _cursor.close();
      _statement.release();
    }
  }
}
```